# REST API details to fetch Keycloak user data

Tags: keycloak

I want to retrieve some of the parameter/values from keycloak (Maria db) data through REST API.

**These are the parameters which i am looking to retrieve from Keycloak through REST API:**

Realm Name

Realm ID

Keycloak Admin-Users

Username

Email

First Name

Last Name

Realm ID

User Enabled

Is there anyone using REST APIs to fetch these details from keycloak, Could you please share the REST API URL details for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Create service user, make sure user has role "realm-management"->"view-users" (might be query-users as well)

Process is simple: do login to keycloak with service user (keep password and/or user name encoded in the properties file), make request to keycloak with accessToken in authorisation header to

**GET http://{yourdomainadress}/auth/admin/realms/{yourrealmname}/users**

A way to login to keycloak using REST API:

**POST http://{yourdomainadress}/auth/realms/{yourrealmname}/protocol/openid-connect/token**

Headers:

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body x-www-form-urlencoded:

client_id: your-client

username: user-you-are-using

password: password-for-user

grant_type: password

client_secret: 11112222-3333-4444-5555-666666666666 (client secret is required if client "Access Type"="confidential")

Comment: Amazing, it works! For clarification, I would like to add that the access token retrieved from the login request should be passed in the GET request header as follow:
"Authorization: Bearer {access_token_here}".

Answer (score 0):

You should edit this api url with the information of your keycloak instance.

**http://{yourdomainadress}/auth/admin/realms/{yourrealmname}/users**

You can not get Realm ID with api.
Check the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) for the users api parameters